# Are symmetry operations commutative or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetry

My book (Bishop, David m. Group Theory and Chemistry) states, that $C_3C_3^{-1} = E$ and $C_3^{-1}C_3 = E$.

[image: commutative]

After that it shows an non-commutative example:

[image: non-commutative]

Ok. But then they say that $(PQ)R = P(QR) = PQR$.
Actually, the operations are always applied from right to left, but here the sequence $Q, P, R$ and $R, Q, P$ is apparently the same. This is what confuses me a little, although it was shown before that it generally depends on the sequence of the linkage.

Comment: Where are $P$,$Q$, and $R$ in your picture? I can't see them

Comment: Yes, commutativity doesn't always hold but associativity is actually a requirement for a group operation.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

> Are symmetry operations commutative or not?

No.

Consider the rotations and reflections of an equilateral triangle. It is not difficult to see that, if we label the vertices of the triangle by $1,2,$ and $3$, then the symmetries correspond to the group $S_3$ of permutations of three elements. (In fact, this can be made precise: the group $D_3$ of symmetries of an equilateral triangle is *isomorphic* to $S_3$.)

However, $(12)(23)=(312)$, whereas $(23)(12)=(132)\neq (312)$.

Thus $D_3$ is not abelian.

But all groups are associative, which is to say that for all $a,b,c\in G$, where $G$ is a group, we have

$$a(bc)=(ab)c.$$

Comment: Ok, so i can put the brackets how i want to. Two questions come to my mind, why use clamps at all then? And don't the brackets still change the sequence? a(bc)=(ab)c = bca = abc

Comment: A priori, @iwab, parentheses are needed, but it is not too difficult to show by induction that, due to associativity (being an axiom), we can place them anywhere without issue, and even omit them entirely. Some algebraic structures require parentheses, though, like some quasigroups.

Comment: You can't move the $b$ in front of the $a$ just be rearranging the parentheses. The parentheses tell  you the order in which to do the arithmetic operations, not the order in which the operands appear. Different orders of operations produce the same answer. Sometimes some orders are more efficient to compute than others.

Comment: @EthanBolker "Different orders of operations produce the same answer."- but doesn't the second image in my question (b) show the exact opposite? So i'm a little unsure, when brackets are set they tell me to apply these operations (inside the bracket from right to left) first and then the rest, thats why I dont understand that a(bc)=(ab)c is true for symmetrie operators.

Comment: I think you have commutativity and associativity confused, @iwab. Please revise their definitions.

Comment: The pictures deal with the product of two symmetries, so the question about associativity (placing parentheses) never comes up. In the first picture you have the product of a rotation and its inverse. That comes out the identity in either order. In the second picture you have the product of a reflection and a rotation. There the order matters. The product operation is not commutative. But it is associative.